# Is there a way to update Outlook contacts from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

So I have a list of contacts in Outlook (imported a long time ago from an Excel sheet). People move, people get new email addresses and so on, so the Excel list is updated. Is it possible to import the Excel file again and overwriting/updating existing contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import from a CSV file in Outlook, you can choose between options :

- Replace duplicates with items impported
- Allow duplicates do be created
- Do not import duplicate items

Did you want to automate the import with macro ? or was it only one shot and handled "by hand" ?

Regards,

Max

Comment: just by hand. Do you know how duplicates are detected?

Comment: i don't know and MS is not really clear about it : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/delete-duplicate-contacts-HA001126714.aspx. You'd better try on several examples (Name / E-mail) and tell us what happens.